# Writing socket stream to file takes long

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I have code which writes the inputstream from a socket to a file with a bufferedreader. This works, but for some reason it takes a long time for the bufferedwriter to finish writing to the file (multiple minutes, of which less than first 2 seconds are spent writing to the file). The code is as follows:

```
@Override
    public void handleRequest() {
        Socket s = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        Writer writer = null;
        PrintWriter pw = null;

        try {
            s = new Socket(this.getHost(), this.getPort());
            pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            pw.println(this.getHTTPCommand());
            pw.println(this.getHostCommand());
            pw.print(ENDOFREQUEST);
            pw.flush();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

            String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            String filePath = this.getPath();
            if(this.getPath().equals("/")){
                filePath = "/index.html";
            }
            Path completePath = Paths.get(currentDir, filePath);
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(completePath.toString()), "utf-8"));
            String t;
            while((t = br.readLine()) != null){
                writer.write(t + "\n");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if (writer != null) {
                    writer.close();
                }
                if (br != null) {
                    br.close();
                }
                if (pw != null) {
                    pw.close();
                }
                if (s != null) {
                    s.close();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to `flush` the `BufferedWriter` after your while loop.  It doesn't affect how your code works, but a try-with-resources would tidy up the code as well.